# Dupe hammer didn't work

Tags: support, dupehammer

I have a gold badge for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). I recently closed [Why does IntelliJ skipping a line when coding java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72050401/why-does-intellij-skipping-a-line-when-coding-java) as a dupe, but it didn't close. Is there something going on with dupe hammer functionality?

Comment: Since when do you have a gold hammer in [tag:jave]?

Comment: (But if you edit the tag, then someone with a gold hammer in java may come along and close it as a  dupe if appropriate)

Comment: @Makoto I see it in my profile. err...nvm, now I see the typo.

Comment: @Makoto I removed [tag:intellij-idea] from the question after my close vote. I didn't add or remove [tag:java].

Comment: OIC...the tag had a typo...wow, that's easy to miss.

Comment: Yeah, that typo ([tag:jave] instead of [tag:java]) is tough to spot.

Comment: What proportion of uses of that tag are typos for the java tag? Maybe it should be renamed something more distinctive.

Comment: [[tag:jave-is-not-java]], @khelwood?

Comment: @CodyGray That would probably cut it down a few per cent.

Comment: My vote would go for [javE-e-from-extraterrestrial-not-java-100%-different-keep-that-in-mind]

Comment: Annoyingly, there is also another similar tag. And amusingly found this question which was only tagged with both incorrect tags: [[tag:jave]] and [[tag:javers]] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPx8W.png

Comment: @khelwood to answer your question: a large proportion were typos. I went through the tag to remove it where it's not appropriate. There were two pages of questions. Each page is 50 questions, so maybe 60-70 to start with. I didn't really check. Now there are 12 left. Most were "java" misspelled but there were a couple where *maybe* the question asker meant "javascript" (but that wasn't really appropriate, either). And a few which weren't really Java related.